# Sqlite Query Loop not working

Tags: ios, sql, database, xcode, sqlite

i am trying to run this query but neither NSLog is working nor the alert is showing .. query does not executes it does not gets into the if loop

```
viewDidLoad{


pin_lat = pinAnnotation.coordinate.latitude;

NSLog(@"pin latitude is %f",pin_lat); //This one is only working

sqlite3_stmt *statement;

         NSString *qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM site WHERE latitude LIKE %f AND longitude LIKE %f",pin_lat,pin_long];

   if (sqlite3_open([qsql UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK){
     //  sqlite3_exec(db, [statement UTF8String],NULL, NULL, &err == SQLITE_OK);

         NSLog(@"QUERY IS WORKING IN OPEN DB");

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [qsql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)== SQLITE_OK)
    {
         NSLog(@"QUERY IS WORKING IN DB PREPARE");

        while(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            /* char *field1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);  getting name value in field1
             NSString *field1Str =
             [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: field1];
             [field1Str release];*/

            NSLog(@"QUERY IS WORKING");

            UIAlertView *alert_pin = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Cannot create a duplicate location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];

            [alert_pin show];
            [alert_pin release];


        }

        //—-deletes the compiled statement from memory—-
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

    else{

        [mapView addAnnotation:pinAnnotation];  // this is working ... but i want the if loop to also work

    }

}

 sqlite3_close(db);
 // not exist to show alert
}
```

what is wrong with my query why is it not executing the query and opening the DB or printing the Log's inside the if loop ... can any one correct my code  .. any help?

Comment: NSLog the query in console and execute it on the sqlite manager. I think there is some issue with the query

Comment: yes it works .. even if i make the query "SELECT * from site" .. it should enter in the loop and display the NSLog which is also not working ...

Comment: i have to just execute the query and show the alert ..

Comment: is the NSlogs inside sqlite_open and sqlite_prepare is working ?

Comment: No none of them is working ...

Comment: I noticed the issue, posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Midhun is correct. I'd further advise that each of these `if` statements should have a corresponding `else` clause that displays the return code as well as, if possible, the error message. Or, equivalently, check for failure at each step and, if so, report diagnostic information and return. Thus, it might look like:

```
int rc;
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

NSString *qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM site WHERE latitude LIKE %f AND longitude LIKE %f",pin_lat,pin_long];

if ((rc = sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &db)) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"%s sqlite3_open failed: (%d)", __FUNCTION__, rc);
    return;
}

NSLog(@"QUERY IS WORKING IN OPEN DB");

if ((rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [qsql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"%s sqlite3_prepare_v2 failed: \"%s\" (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db), rc);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return;
}

NSLog(@"QUERY IS WORKING IN DB PREPARE");

while ((rc = sqlite3_step(statement)) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    const char *field0 = (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0); // getting name value in field1
    NSString *field0Str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:field0];

    NSLog(@"QUERY IS WORKING: %@", field0Str);

    UIAlertView *alert_pin = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Cannot create a duplicate location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];

    [alert_pin show];
    [alert_pin release];
}

if (rc != SQLITE_DONE)
{
    NSLog(@"%s sqlite3_step failed: \"%s\" (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db), rc);
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(db);
}

if ((rc = sqlite3_finalize(statement)) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"%s sqlite3_finalize failed: \"%s\" (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db), rc);
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(db);
}

sqlite3_close(db);
```

Answer (score 0):

This line causes the issue:

```
 if (sqlite3_open([qsql UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
```

The parameter is incorrect in the above code.

**You are passing the sql query instead of database path.**

Because this the database is not opened and the if condition fails. That's why you are not getting any output.

Pass database path as first parameter of `sqlite3_open`. It'll work.

Comment: Oh yes .. this one worked .. if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) .. but after this NSLog(@"QUERY IS WORKING IN OPEN DB"); again it not goes into the loop

Comment: Use the query select *from site

Comment: i am using select * from site now but it is not going in the loop .. i get this "QUERY IS WORKING IN OPEN DB" on console and not the next NSLog and neither the alert ..

Comment: @user1900226: check there is any value inside the table then also check the table is created on the database

Comment: yup database's all other query are running in other files.

Comment: @user1900226 have an `else` statement that does a `NSLog(@"%s", sqlite_errmsg(db));` if you have an error. This is especially critical for `sqlite_prepare_v2`, in which the error message will typically tell you what's wrong with your SQL.