# sql select statement not working

Tags: ios, sql, database, sqlite

I have asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003129/sqlite-query-loop-not-working/14003267#comment19332319_14003267)

when i run this query 
 `NSString *qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM site"];`

it works fine but when i try this query 
 `NSString *qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM site WHERE latitude LIKE %f  AND longitude LIKE %f",pin_lat,pin_long];`
it does not works while i can print the value of lat, long in console with NSLog(@"lat = %f and long=%f",pin_lat,pin_long) it prints the values correct so why it is not taking the value in the query?

I tried modifying the query but it does not work at all

the modified query is like-`NSString *qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM site WHERE latitude LIKE \"%%%f%%\"  AND longitude LIKE \"%%%f%%\" ",pin_lat,pin_long];`

but when i try to type the latitude manually it works fine

```
NSString *qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from site where latitude='-31.7306'"];
```

How should i modify my query so that i can run it ..

Comment: xcode is an IDE only, this is not xcode related

Comment: What do you mean by "does not works"

Comment: i mean the query does not works and then i can't get into the while loop ... it skips the while ( .. SQLITE_ROW) loop and i want the while loop to work ..

Answer (score 1):

I guess, its because you are using `AND` in your query, so it'll select `row` which satisfies two conditions. Try using `OR` instead of `AND` like

```
NSString *qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM site WHERE latitude LIKE '%f' OR longitude LIKE '%f'",pin_lat,pin_long];
```

or, If you want the row that meets both condition, then you need to have that value in your database.

or, it might happen because `LIKE` try to match exactly what you gave, you need to use `%` sign to match anything after it continues with that variable. if you want to match your latitude like how you mentioned, you need to use query like this

```
NSString *qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM site WHERE latitude LIKE '%.2f%%' OR longitude LIKE '%.2f'",pin_lat,pin_long];
```

This'll match any value after its precision 2 in that latitude or longitude value. It'll match the following values.
**19.241111111

19.242222222

19.243333333**

Comment: i tried this without and also NSString *qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM site WHERE latitude LIKE '%f' ,pin_lat]; and it still not works ..

Comment: i checked NSString *qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM site WHERE latitude LIKE '%.2f%%' OR longitude LIKE '%.2f'",pin_lat,pin_long]; is also not working ... nor this NSString *qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM site WHERE latitude LIKE '%.2f%%'",pin_lat];

Comment: can you post some of your `pinlat and pinlong` values.

Comment: NSLog(@"pin lat is %f",pin_lat); outputs me -31.7306 and then this is working fine  NSString *qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from site where latitude='-31.7306'"]; but when i use this query SELECT * from site where latitude = %f",pin_lat .. it does not works

Comment: some of the pin_lat,pin_long values are : -31.7306,152.794 :-31.7353,152.792 : -33.7256,150.303 .... both the lat and long are in float and are present in DB

Comment: its like same, but only thing is you need to use `LIKE` with `%` operator. When you try to print your query string, if it prints as `SELECT * FROM yourTable where latitude like '-31.73%'` surely, it'll retrieve that row. Or check are you having `name` field in your `site` table or not.

Comment: yes it prints that in log .. i think it will work now .. but somehow i am getting some error after i run this query sqlite3_step failed: "unknown error" (100)

Comment: plz tell me one more thing if my DB is on the server how can i run query so that it takes output from the server because i think it is not updating the local DB in the app so i think i have to run query so that it can connect to the server and return me the result with the data that is on the server ...

Answer (score 0):

If latitude and longitude are numbers, `like` might not work like expected.

What `like` does is search for a string that fits the pattern, doing a `like` without any `%`'s basically boils down to doing a slower version of `=`.

Comment: lat and long are float .. and it does not work without LIKE also i tried NSString *qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from site where latitude = %f",pin_lat]; .. still not works for me

Comment: SQLite likes to play fast and loose with data types, so if you tell it to treat them as strings, it will :). Replace the `like` with `=` and make sure that the database contains the exact value you are searching for.

Comment: i checked every thing it works if i straight away put the value of lat that is printed on the console ... NSLog(@"lat is = %f",pin_lat); this value if i enter in my query it runs fine but if i put %f in query it's not working .. i tried everything

Comment: Can you `NSLog` the exact string you are sending to the database, post it here and execute it directly on the database?

Comment: i got this query in log .. SELECT * from site where latitude = 37.785834 ... but it should be SELECT * from site where latitude = -37.785834 .. why the negative sign is not their in query that's why it's not working